# Foreach up one number for each

Tags: php, codeigniter

Struggling a little on this one.

This is my foreach code

```
<?php
$subtotal = 0;
foreach ($go_cart['contents'] as $cartkey=>$product):?>

        <td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_0" value="Description" /></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And for this line

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_0" value="Description" /></td>
```

I need it to up by one for each foreach. Such as:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_0" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_1" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_2" value="Description" /></td>
```

I'm pretty sure you have the quick solution for me on this one...

Thanks guys!, appreciate it.

HERE IS WHAT I FORGOT TO MENTION:

I have multiple fields for this action. So i have description, itemcount, itemamount etc.

So they should be like this

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_0" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemcount_0" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemamount_0" value="Description" /></td>
```

But with the solution you sent me i get.

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_1" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemcount_2" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemamount_3" value="Description" /></td>
```

Sorry, my mistake!...

Comment: Too much code, but why don't you declare `$i = 0` before the loop and then use it, and of course increment it `$i++;`.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
$subtotal = 0;
```

to

```
$subtotal = 0;
$i = 0;
```

Then do the following:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemdescription_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemcount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Description" /></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="itemamount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Description" /></td>
```

Right BEFORE you close your outer `foreach()` loop do this on its own line:

```
$i++;
```

What you are doing is first initializing the variable `$i` by setting it to `0`. You then output the current value of `$i`. Then you will use the [post-increment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) with `$i` as `$i++` at the end of your loop to increase its value by `1` so the next time it is output on next run of the loop it will be increased by `1`.

Comment: Forgit to mention one thing, added it in the bottom of description above. That's the issue i'm having...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
  {
  echo "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"itemdescription_" . $i . "value=\"Description\" /></td>"."\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Forgit to mention one thing, added it in the bottom of description above. That's the issue i'm having...